# Symfony Seralizer doesn't serialize OneToOne relation / Doctrin Proxy

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine

I'm trying to serialize a Entity that has a OneToOne relation to a Image Entity.
When dumping the Entity I can see that the Image Entity is a Doctrine Proxy and not initialized.

It also doesn't show up in the JSON response when trying to access the Endpoint.
I've tried fetch="EAGER" with no success.

How do I go about serializing this to the "Expected Response" ?

Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7
  }
]
```

Expected Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "image": {
        "webView": "someUrl"
    }
  }
]
```

Entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BatteryTypeRepository::class)
 */
class BatteryType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @Groups({"type"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Image::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     *
     * @Groups({"type"})
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @return Image|null
     */
    public function getImage(): ?Image
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(?Image $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Image Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ImageRepository::class)
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\EventSubscriber\ImageListener"})
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"type"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * Auto generated by entity listener
     * @var string
     */
    private $tempFilename;

    /**
     * @var File
     * @Assert\Image()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Groups({"type"})
     */
    private $webView;

    /** Getters & Setters */
}
```

ImageListener:

```php
class ImageListener
{
    /**
     * @var S3FileManagerInterface
     */
    private S3FileManagerInterface $fileManager;

    public function __construct(S3FileManagerInterface $fileManager)
    {
        $this->fileManager = $fileManager;
    }

    public function postLoad(Image $image, LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $image->setWebView(
            $this->fileManager->getUrl($image->getFilename())
        );

        if (!$image->getTempFilename()) {
            $image->setTempFilename($image->getFilename());
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
    public function getBatteryTypes(BatteryTypeRepository $batteryTypeRepository): Response
    {
        $batteryTypes = $batteryTypeRepository->findAll();
        $view = $this->view($batteryTypes, Response::HTTP_OK);
        $view->getContext()->setGroups(["type"]);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```

Comment: Consider creating a DQL query and select both the Battery and Image entities.  That will eliminate the proxy completely and at least narrow down any remaining problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem apparently was just cache related

Comment: I have a similar problem. On one entity it works, but on the other it doesn't. What cache clear command did you run? I tried `cache:clear`, `doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`, `doctrine:cache:clear-query`, and `doctrine:cache:clear-result` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Image` entity, you have to add the `@Groups({"type"})` annotation for the `webView` attribute.

Comment: I adjusted my post with the Image Entity source

Comment: Is the annotation properly imported in `Image`? (just want to eliminate this possibility)